# Get Conditions for Variable to be Real

Tags: symbolic, complex, resolve

I have a complex definition of a few variables (that I got using `s = Solve[1 - a x^2 - x^3 == 0, x]`) and I now want to know under what conditions of "a" will each of the solutions be real.

For example, one of the variables I have is `r3=-(a/3) + ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) a^2)/(
 3 2^(2/3) (-27 + 2 a^3 + 3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[27 - 4 a^3])^(
  1/3)) + ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-27 + 2 a^3 + 
    3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[27 - 4 a^3])^(1/3))/(6 2^(1/3))`, I want to know under what conditions will r3 be a real number.

I have tried simplifying this to the most basic example where I want to know what the conditions on a+b*I need to be so that it is real (where the answer I expect would be b=0), so I tried using `Resolve[a + b I, Reals]` but this does not give me the answer I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a domain specification to [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) or [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve):

```
NSolve[1 - a x^2 - x^3 == 0, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> ConditionalExpression[Root[-1. + a #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
>       a > 1.88988 || a < 1.88988]}, {x -> 
>      ConditionalExpression[Root[-1. + a #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
>       a > 1.88988]}, {x -> 
>      ConditionalExpression[Root[-1. + a #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3], 
>       a > 1.88988]}}